# Calculate and retrieve SQL data, additional columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, formatting

I have a small table with 3 columns

```
Title | StartMonth | EndMonth
```

it has the below data

```
ESX Upgrades 6.7            8   10
Fix SQL                     9   11
Universe Red Hat Migration  7   12
Upgrade Aventail device     9   9
Learn coding                11  12
```

I would like to be able to run a query/calculation to retrieve the data that can be in a presented in a calendar style output similar to below

```
ESX Host Upgrades 6.7       August September October
Fix SQL                     September October November
Universe Red Hat Migration  July August September October November December
Upgrade Aventail device     September
Lean coding                 November December
```

Any ideas / info would be greatly appreciated

I believe can use CASE functionality to project the numbers to months, but need to work out how to get the months in between the start and end month.

Comment: Please tag your question with the database that you are running: mysql, oracle, sqlserver...?

Comment: Sqlserver added
cheers

Answer (score 1):

You can have a table containing the month number and month name mapping and then use CROSS APPLY to get the corresponding month names and then aggregate them against the title.

```sql
DECLARE @t table(Title varchar(500), StartMonth int, EndMonth int)

INSERT INTO @t
values
('ESX Upgrades 6.7'            ,8   ,10),
('Fix SQL'                     ,9   ,11),
('Universe Red Hat Migration'  ,7   ,12),
('Upgrade Aventail device'     ,9   ,9 ),
('Learn coding'                ,11  ,12);

SELECT * FROM @t

;WITH CTE_NumberMonth as
(
SELECT * 
FROM
(
VALUES
(1,'January')
,(2,'February')
,(3,'March')
,(4,'April')
,(5,'May')
,(6,'June')
,(7,'July')
,(8,'August')
,(9,'September')
,(10,'October')
,(11,'November')
,(12,'December')
) AS t(Num,MName)
)
SELECT Title , STRING_AGG(it.mName,' ') AS Months
FROM @t as ot
CROSS APPLY (
SELECT MName from CTE_NumberMonth
where Num between ot.StartMonth and ot.EndMonth) as it
GROUP BY Title
```

```
+----------------------------+-------------------------------------------------+
|           Title            |                     Months                      |
+----------------------------+-------------------------------------------------+
| ESX Upgrades 6.7           | August September October                        |
| Fix SQL                    | September October November                      |
| Learn coding               | November December                               |
| Universe Red Hat Migration | July August September October November December |
| Upgrade Aventail device    | September                                       |
+----------------------------+-------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: thanks, i actually need something like this
12 columns for the months
and then when the project has the month, put the project name in the column
 SELECT
  CASE WHEN PU.Month = '1' THEN P.[Title] END AS January 
  ,CASE WHEN PU.Month = '2' THEN P.[Title] END AS February
  ,CASE WHEN PU.Month = '3' THEN P.[Title] END AS March
  ,CASE WHEN PU.Month = '4' THEN P.[Title] END AS April
  ,CASE WHEN PU.Month = '5' THEN P.[Title] END AS May
 FROM table

Comment: @braddo, please add your answer. so, it is helpful for others in future

Comment: i don't have an answer yet, i was just adding additional info

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive CTE for this:

```
with cte as (
      select str, lo + 1 as lo,
             convert(varchar(max), datename(month, dateadd(month, lo - 1, '2000-01-01'))) as months, hi, 1 as lev
      from t
      union all
      select str, lo + 1 as lo,
              convert(varchar(max), months + ' ' + datename(month, dateadd(month, lo - 1, '2000-01-01'))) as months, hi, lev + 1
      from cte
      where lo <= hi
     )
select *
from cte
where lo = hi + 1;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1d42825f5596087a8c534dffaf57bdfc) is a db<>fiddle.